# Error when running Mysql batch file

Tags: mysql, sql, windows-vista, terminal

I have a .sql file on my computer at C:\Users\Owner\Documents\file.sql
(Windows Vista) that just creates a database and a simple table within.
In mysql at the command line i enter

source C:\Users\Owner\Documents\newbie.sql;

the query seems to work ok but just before it shows me the successfully created table it outputs the following errors that seem to be related to how i entered the file name:

```
ERROR:
Unknown command '\U'.

ERROR:
Unknown command '\O'.

ERROR:
Unknown command '\D'.

ERROR:
Unknown command '\n'.
```

Pardon the newbie error...whats the fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using forward slash `/` in place of back slash `\` in file path:

```
C:/Users/Owner/Documents/newbie.sql
```

or put it between double quotes (`"`)

Comment: backslash '\' is an escape character for MySql. You can see here for more info:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-commands.html (look for `delimiter`)

Comment: I came here in search of answers for the same question. By replacing the path string with a UNC path, I eliminated all but one "Unknown command '\A'." that persists.  Along the way, I ran net share, which informed me that Windows 10 Fall Creators Update lists F$ as a default share for my 7200 RPM magnetic hard drive, along with the more or less expected C# for the boot volume, which is on a solid state drive.