# MySQL error in MySQL when reading a dump file

Tags: mysql, wamp

Trying to read in a data dump file using MySQL console version 5.6.17 as a part of WAMP configuration. I already have the database configured.

I get the following error when I run the command:

```
    -> source C:\wamp\www\nlbuysell.com\setup\database\dump\buysell_beta.sql;
Show warnings disabled.
Show warnings disabled.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\n'.
--------------
c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/bin/mysql.exe  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.17, for Win64
 (x86_64)

Connection id:          17
Current database:
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Using delimiter:        atabasedumpbuys
Server version:         5.6.17 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             localhost via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    cp850
Conn.  characterset:    cp850
TCP port:               3306
Uptime:                 2 hours 53 min 29 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 2245  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 7706  Flush tables: 1  Open
 tables: 208  Queries per second avg: 0.215
```

Reviewed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905523/error-when-running-mysql-batch-file) and tried all forms of of switching from \ to / and using 'single quote' to "double quote". When I make any changes the console just moves to a new line, it's like nothing even happens.

The data won't load. Why is this occurring?

Comment: Your `Using delimieter:` setting seems wrong.  How did it get set to that?

Comment: @NovaDenizen I have no idea. I have used this same script in other deploys but on my new system it's complaining with the \n I don't think it's even reading the source

Answer (score 0):

This seems like you have a dump file with UNIX line endings.

Open the file in a decent editor ( not notepad ) and convert the format to DOS.

notepad++ is a free very good editor which will allow you to make this type change

Comment: Unable to open the file it is too large. I uploaded this file before without any issues. On a new install of wamp it seems to be rejected. Lucky I had a backup of the original. I copied that over and used the previous database.

Do you have another program you could suggest that I could use for future reference?

Comment: Another program to do what? And how large is the backup file?

Comment: My data dump file is an SQL file, it is almost 1GB. I had WAMP backed up, and with a new install the sql dump is reporting the error I mentioned above. So I just took my previous copy, which I imported the data successfully, and copied it onto my new system.